# Add an "All" item to kendo ui listview populated by a remote datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I am building a website using MVC 4, Web API, and Kendo UI controls.

On my page I am using a Kendo UI Listview to filter my grid.  I'm trying to add an "ALL" option as the first item in my listview.

Here is the **listview**:

```
var jobsfilter = $("#jobfilter").kendoListView({
            selectable: "single",
            loadOnDemand: false,
            template: "<div class='pointercursor' id=${FilterId}>${FilterName}</div>",
            dataSource: filterDataSource,
            change: function (e) {
                var itm = this.select().index(), dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[itm];
                if (dataItem.FilterId !== 0) {
                    var $filter = new Array();
                    $filter.push({ field: "JobStatusId", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.FilterId });
                    jgrid.dataSource.filter($filter);
                } else {
                    jgrid.dataSource.filter({});
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is my **datasource**:

```
 var filterDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "api/Filter"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: { id: "FilterId" }
            }
        });
```

I have tried a few different methods to make this happen:

- I can make it work if I attach it to a button - but I need it there
  when the data loads.
- If I add it to the **dataBound** event of the listview, it causes the
  databound event to go into a loop and adds the item a bunch (IE) or kills the browser (firefox). Adding preventDefault did nothing.
- I've read up on adding a function to the **Read** paramter of the
  datasource, but I think that is simply not the correct place to do
  it.

Based on what I've read, I think that I should be able to do it in the dataBound event of the listview and that my implementation is incorrect.  Here is the listview with dataBound event added that crashes my browser (Firefox) - or adds about 50 "All" items to the listview (IE).

```
var jobsfilter = $("#jobfilter").kendoListView({
            selectable: "single",
            loadOnDemand: false,
            template: "<div class='pointercursor' id=${FilterId}>${FilterName}</div>",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "api/Filter"
                    }
                }
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                var dsource = $("#jobfilter").data("kendoListView").dataSource;
                dsource.insert(0, { FilterId: 0, FilterName: "All" });
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            change: function (e) {
                var itm = this.select().index(), dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[itm];
                if (dataItem.FilterId !== 0) {
                    var $filter = new Array();
                    $filter.push({ field: "JobStatusId", operator: "eq", value: dataItem.FilterId });
                    jgrid.dataSource.filter($filter);
                } else {
                    jgrid.dataSource.filter({});
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add it server-side? 
Anyway, if you want to do it in `dataBound`, just check whether it exists and only add if it doesn't:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
    var dsource = this.dataSource;
    if (dsource.at(0).FilterName !== "All") {
        dsource.insert(0, {
            FilterId: 0,
            FilterName: "All"
        });
    }
},
```

As an explanation to the problem you're seeing: you're creating an infinite loop since inserting an element in the data source will trigger the change event and the list view will refresh and bind again (and thus trigger `dataBound`).

You could also encapsulate this in a custom widget:

```
(function ($, kendo) {
    var ui = kendo.ui,
        ListView = ui.ListView;

    var CustomListView = ListView.extend({
        init: function (element, options) {
            // base call to widget initialization
            ListView.fn.init.call(this, element, options);

            this.dataSource.insert(0, {
                FilterId: 0,
                FilterName: "All"
            });
        },

        options: {
            name: "CustomListView"
        }
    });

    ui.plugin(CustomListView);
})(window.jQuery, window.kendo);
```

Comment: I currently add it server-side, but I don't like doing that.  The "All" selection is only pertinent to the UI actions and not pertinent to the actual data coming from the server side.  In my mind that means it should not exist in the data coming from the server (although it could be argued otherwise).

Comment: And boy do I feel dumb at the moment, I never once thought about checking the item at 0.

Comment: well, from that perspective you might want to extend the ListView widget and add the item in the init method - that way it's all encapsulated

Comment: Success!  Thank you for pointing out my (now) completely obvious omission.  I was aware of the infinite loop issue - I was obviously stuck on stopping the event from bubbling up vs. intelligently checking before execution.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript in general, Kendo UI and jQuery - but I will look into extending the widget since that is a logical way to handle it.  Thanks for the assistance.